# replace bookmarklet, with slashes

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I am building a bookmarklet to replace **facebook.com/** with **rillist.com/?id=**
what i'm using now is:

```
javascript:
  (function() {
    window.location=window.location.toString().replace(/facebook.com/,'rillist.com\?id=');
  })()
```

but that yields:
http://www.rillist.com/?id=/example
any idea on how to remove that pesky slash in order to yield:
http://www.rillist.com/?id=example
?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your regex doesn't match the last forward slash.

Try changing the regex to this:

```
/facebook.com\//
```